# What Messaging App Displays this Notification?

Tags: applications

What Messaging App Runs this notification?
[image]

Disregard the darker app running in the background, that is just what happened to be open already when the text message was received.

My wife lets the kids play around with her phone and she has a million apps installed, including several different messaging apps, several of which I am not familiar with.

Whenever she receives a text message, there is the native notification that appears at the top of the screen (that is OK), but shortly thereafter, there is also an annoying popup that comes up, interrupting phone calls and everything, that displays the message and then only offers two options: 1) dismiss, or 2) reply with a voice to text message.

Above is a photo of her phone displaying the message.

This is a Galaxy 4 phone, running Android.

If I could just figure out what App is running the notification, I think I might be able to disable it...

Anyone recognize this?

Comment: First, you should consider editing your image to direct our attention to the parts depicting the issue in it. Second, have [tag:adb] setup in PC and whenever that popup shows up again, run `adb shell dumpsys window windows`. That output would contain the package name of the app somewhere in it.

Comment: Go to **App manager>Running Apps** to view all the apps running at that time without closing this popup. You'll get some clue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you gentlemen for your comments. They indeed did help me to identify what app was creating this notification...

The App is called **Dragon**. Our daughter installed without us knowing.

The notifications have been disabled. Thank you for your help.